# How to create an MySQL conditional function that iterates through a table and takes multiple parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, stored-functions, mysql-5.7

I am very new to PL/SQL, but I would like to populate an empty field for all entries in a table, based on the values of several fields in a giving row. 
So the logic I would like to put in place is, but there are several thing in which I need to keep in mind when setting up a table for a Car Dealership...

First, group by the distinct used_car_ids, then update the column based on.....

1. If the used_car_id column is equal to the new_car_id, and both the drive_mode and saftey_rating is **1**, then set the Parking_Spot number to 1 as highest precedence.
2. If the used_car_id column is equal to the new_car_id, but the drive_mode is **1** and saftey_rating is 2, then set the Parking_Spot column to 2 or the available consecutive Parking_Spot number

   - If there are more conditions similar to this, but only the saftey_rating is different then, I would like to keep increasing the Parking_Spot number to the next available consecutive Parking_spot number for that entry
3. If the used_car_id column is equal to the new_car_id, but the drive_mode is **2** and saftey_rating is 1, then set the Parking_Spot column to 3, or the next available Parking_Spot number
4. If the used_car_id column is equal to the new_car_id, but the drive_mode is **2** and saftey_rating is 2, then set the Parking_Spot number to 4, or the next available Parking_Spot number

   - Same rules apply, as above.

If the highest precedence case isn't met then it should treat the 2 use case as the highest and put that as Parking_Spot=**1**.

This is a small picture, of what I would ideally want. So as you can see in the picture the Parking Spot number is 1, and 2 depending if the used_car_id, new_car_id, drive_mode, and safety_rating are 1 and 2, but once the used_car_id and new_car_id is different the Parking Spot number increases to 3 and 4.

[image: Used Car Dealer Table]

I'm assuming I need a function to input 4 parameters and based on those fields then I return a number as the Parking Spot. But I am still a bit unsure of how to go about it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: PL/SQL is the procedural portion language of the Oracle Database, but you have mysql tagged. Which are you actually using?

Comment: Tag properly!!!!  If this is Oracle, why do I see `MySQL` tag on your question???

Comment: I'm sorry please bear with me. I didn't know that PL/SQL is only for Oracle. This is a MySQL database. I just edited the name of the question and the tags. Thank you to all for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your tags whether you're actually using the Oracle database or MySQL. This answer assumes the former.

Your question has a couple gaps, but it seems like you want to give each row a sequential number based on the `drive_mode` and `safety_rating`. You mention "`used_car_id column is equal to the new_car_id`" several times, but never mention what you want to do when they are not equal.

For the question as written, it seems that this can be solved in a fairly straightforward way using analytic functions. In this case, we'll simply tell the function to order the rows by `drive_mode_id` and `safety_rating` and give each row from the resulting order a consecutive number:

```
SELECT id,
       used_car_id,
       new_car_id,
       car_features_id,
       drive_mode_id,
       safety_rating,
       ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY drive_mode, safety_rating)
           AS parking_spot
FROM   your_table
WHERE  used_car_id = new_car_id
```

---

It looks like MySQL supports analytic functions (aka window functions) as of 8.0.2, so the above solution should still work if you are using that version or later (if not, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql) might help).

To update that to also consider `used_car_id = new_car_id` as a sort condition, you'll need to add a conditional to the ORDER BY:

```
SELECT id,
       used_car_id,
       new_car_id,
       car_features_id,
       drive_mode_id,
       safety_rating,
       ROW_NUMBER ()
       OVER (
           ORDER BY
               CASE WHEN used_car_id = new_car_id THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
               drive_mode,
               safety_rating)
           AS parking_spot
FROM   your_table
```

This is untested, so I can't guarantee that this is entirely syntactically correct, but it should be close.

Comment: Thanks for your response Allan, and I'm using Mysql database. I'm sorry that was another point I wanted to bring up as well. If the used_car_id and new_car_id are not equal then it should be treated as lower precedence compared to the ones which are equal. So, if there is a row with

Comment: Thanks for your response Allan, and I'm using Mysql database. I'm sorry I meant  to mention that point. But if the used_car_id and new_car_id are not equal then it should be treated as lower precedence compared to the ones which are equal. So, if there is a row with both used_car_id and new_car_id equal despite the values of the other columns, and it should have a lower Parking_Spot number than the ones which are not equal. I was thinking I needed to orderBy the Parking_Spots and groupBy the drive_mode. But I like this approach, except it is not able to compile on Workbench, can you assist me?

Comment: Is there a Mysql version to this query, since there are no functions such as ROW_NUMBER or OVER in Mysql which is causing errors.

Comment: I've linked to another question that pertains to emulating that function in the answer.

Comment: So the version which is being used is Mysql 5.7, so that version must've released a few months ago. So if I had to adhere to MySQL 5.7 syntax. Is there a way to replicate that function, or would I have to use pl/sql instead in my situation?

Comment: @user3116769 Isn't it useless if you don't tag properly???  Since you put `PL/SQL` on your title, people assume you are using Oracle.  Now someone give you solution for Oracle and you can't use it.  You just waste everyone's time!!!

Comment: @Eric My Apologies, I'm using a MySQL 5.7 server, and I didn't know that PL/SQL is exclusive to OracleSQL only. This is a bit new to me. So please understand.

Comment: Also, as I mentioned above, I included a link to a question about replicating the `row_number` function in MySQL in the answer. Here it is again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql